# I have a Facebook application error

Tags: facebook

Today I created new application on facebook for my site, but it's giving me an error message:

> Error : Sorry, the application you were using is experiencing a problem. Please try again later.

**My app link:**
http://apps.facebook.com/funzland/

**My app settings:**

- Basic Info

  - App Display Name: Funzland
  - App Namespace: funzland
  - Contact Email: my email
  - App Domain: funzland.com
  - Category: other
- Select how your app integrates with Facebook:
- Website:

  - Site URL: http://www.funzland.com/
- App on Facebook:

  - Canvas URL: apps.facebook.com/funzland/ (http://)
  - Secure Canvas URL: apps.facebook.com/funzland/ (https://)
  - Canvas Page: apps.facebook.com/funzland (http://)

I used the http/https url tag at start of all link in canvas FB app because here I'm new and more then two hyperlinks are not allowed to me in posting that ways, I used to understand helper.

- Apps > Funzland > Advanced:

  - App Type: web
  - Deauthorize Callback:
  - Sandbox Mode: Disabled
- Description:
- Migrations:

  - Remove Deprecated APIs: Enabled
  - Stream post URL security: Disabled
  - Timezone-less events: Enabled
  - Upgrade to Requests 2.0: Enabled
  - Require manage_notifications: Enabled
  - Include recent activity stories: Enabled
  - Enhanced Auth Dialog: Enabled
  - page_hours_format: Enabled
  - Graph Batch API Exception Format: Enabled
- Canvas Settings:

  - Canvas Width: Fixed (760px)
  - Canvas Height: Fluid
  - Social Discovery: Enabled

The above settings I have on FB APP but still not working and giving me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas url should be an url to your page not in facebook.com domain.